# need help reversing an encoder

Tags: python, cryptography

I have made an encoder, but, I think it's too good. So far I can't figure out how to reverse it besides get the key and to remove the extra padding (witch is there to make the output different then the input) Encoder: (Updated)

```
import zlib
import base64

#the alphabet to switch with the letters in our code
enc_alph = 'ashjkl{\':",.<>/?\\_=+-qweuiop125}ZXCVBNM[nmQ];67348!@#$%^rty&*()ASDFGHJKLzxc90vbWERTYUdfgIOP|'

#string is what gets encoded, key is the encode key
string = 'test'
key = list('test')
numbs = []

#getting the ascii values of the keys characters
for i in range(len(key)):
    il = i + 1
    numbs += str(ord(''.join(key[i:il])))

# gets a number from the bellow equation (numb1 + numb2 = numb, numb3 + 5 + numb4 // 2 ** 2 + numb = numb)
fin = int(''.join(numbs[0:1])) + int(''.join(numbs[1:2]))
fin = ((int(''.join(numbs[2:3])) + 5 + int(''.join(numbs[3:4]))) // 2 ** 2) + fin

numbs = []
#getting the ascii values of the letters - 64
for i in range(len(string)):
    il = i + 1
    numbs = numbs + [str(ord(''.join(string[i:il])) - 64)]

out = ''
#switch the chars with the postion in the encoded alphabet and add the 
for i in range(len(numbs)):
    il = i + 1
    out += str(enc_alph[(int(''.join(numbs[i:il]))) + fin:(int(''.join(numbs[i:il]))) + fin + 1])
#compress and base64 encode the key
key = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(''.join(key).encode())).decode()
#add some garbage, a seperator, and the key
out = out + '*GHT#$%^&%^&' + '~' + key
print(out)
```

Decoder (as I have it so far, but, I don't know how to do the rest of it)

```
import base64, zlib
enc_alph = 'ashjkl{\':",.<>/?\\_=+-qweuiop125}ZXCVBNM[nmQ];67348!@#$%^rty&*()ASDFGHJKLzxc90vbWERTYUdfgIOP|'
numbs = []
tmp = []
#string is the encoded string from the encoder
string = 'tQrt*GHT#$%^&%^&~eJwrSS0uAQAEXQHB'

#split the encoded string by the seperator of ~ and set key to equal the second part
data = string.split('~')
key = ''.join(data[1:2])

# decode the key
key = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(key.encode())).decode()
#remove the garbage from the encoded string
data = ''.join(data[0:1]).replace('*GHT#$%^&%^&', '')
#prints the encoded string (tQrt) and the key (test)
print(data)
print(key)
```

Comment: As it stands, your code is really obfuscated right now. It would help if you added comments to document how everything works. Also, just a note, making your own encryption is a bad idea if you're protecting anything you care about, use something well-known and tested.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see how code works. If you have encoder then put code in reverse order and then start test it (ie. using `print()`)

Answer (score 1):

For serious encryption use AES from a library. For practice, but not serious use, try RC4 which is simple though obsolete.

If you really want to use your own encryption, you should develop both encryption and decryption in parallel. Strip your encryption back to the first operation, and immediately write the decryption code for that operation.  Test it and get it working. Then add the second operation to your encryption method. Add the decryption for that operation to the start of your decryption code. Test again.

Add each new operation to the end of your encryption code and the start of your decryption code. Test after each double addition.

Not all encryption operations are reversible, so be careful what ideas you include.

Comment: I currently can't use any non standard lib so I can't do AES, but, I will try your way